# Writing clever type guards for union type and generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, discriminated-union, discriminator

I have following structure:

```js
const fragmentTypes = [
    'Word',
    'Sentence',
] as const;
type FragmentType = typeof fragmentTypes[number];

interface IFragmentData {
    type: FragmentType;
}

interface IFragment<T extends IFragmentData> {
    id: string;
    type: T['type'];
    data: Omit<T, 'type'>;
}

interface IWordFragmentData extends IFragmentData {
    type: 'Word';
    word: string;
}

interface ISentenceFragmentData extends IFragmentData {
    type: 'Sentence';
    sentence: string;
}

type Fragment =
    | IFragment<IWordFragmentData>
    | IFragment<ISentenceFragmentData>;
```

and know have the challenge that I often `filter` Fragments. My current way is by the following type guard:

```js
function isFragmentType<T extends IFragmentData>(t: FragmentType) {
    return (x: Fragment | IFragment<T>): x is IFragment<T> => {
        return x.type === t;
    };
}
console.log(isFragmentType<IWordFragmentData>('Word')({type: 'Word', id: 'test123', data: {word: 'test123'}}));
```

This works fine but leaves the option to combine a `IFragmentData` with the wrong `FragmentType`. For example :  `isFragmentType<IMarkFragmentData>('Sentence')` would be valid code even though 'Sentence' would be the wrong discriminator for the `IMarkFragmentData` type.

Is there a smarter way to write my type guard or even to restructure my typing?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/wQAXGw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (so, no undeclared variables or types).  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: I have modified the code so anyone can test it out on the REPL.

Comment: THANK YOU for the [mcve]!  It really makes answering questions 10 times easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your `isFragmentType()` function is that the type of `t` is not constrained at all to `T`.  I'd probably rewrite it so that `T` represents the `type` property, and use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter the `Fragment` union for the member with that `type` property:

```
function isFragmentType<T extends Fragment['type']>(t: T) {
  return (x: Fragment): x is Extract<Fragment, { type: T }> => {
    return x.type === t;
  };
}
```

You can verify that this works as desired (and you don't have to manually specify `T` since it can be inferred from the type of `t`):

```
function processFragment(f: Fragment) {
  if (isFragmentType("Word")(f)) {
    f.data.word.toUpperCase(); // okay
  } else {
    f.data.sentence.toUpperCase(); // okay
  }
}
```

---

FYI, I'm not sure why `isFragmentType()` is [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), but it doesn't look like it needs to be:

```
function isFragmentType<T extends Fragment['type']>(
  t: T, x: Fragment
): x is Extract<Fragment, { type: T }> {
  return x.type === t;
}

function processFragment(f: Fragment) {
  if (isFragmentType("Word", f)) {
    f.data.word.toUpperCase(); // okay
  } else {
    f.data.sentence.toUpperCase(); // okay
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkvAPbBQAuSAZgE4gDmkwlAKgJ4zRIC8SAbSLEkAcgDqpOgBNRAGmHFRAZQis1iecIC6SEFBLkqAbmGUuyAGINma9hb5Jz3UjVo2W97lAHAArmAARhB02qbCAJbqdDQIyACS1kyeACIglCB4ik4WAFxISbasnNymxAC+hMRRlCGxiEiJHnYAPGxIEAAetcDSBk3JdmkZAHxZIkgR0vlUdFGMZSLOEPlsAqLLomHZ0ukg+QDyYBGUbXJimyOLlZHR9QmSMoWpex3dan2Nz0OvBBPL+QkUlki2IAHdgTNKHNgAthDdqnc4o1VOpgIhvqxhpkuj1PgMipRseMlnkxKieppQUgoHYNCsadD5tcqjluAVmqw+NkAD5fTmneKPaSYol7Ea8-mDVgteIU+mi7FXQjCUCQWDIg5zRgk4g0PzoygRciTKCikoQNpvPEGUXrTbaEYACkoqwAlLqRHQIJQ-HRgEgnZ18qK3flOqakABRboMeCnUXnXBshntcpjXhjP4TL0+v0BzoAOmWfF4-Eo1Iq1Ju2X1huNAZgdFIiCgZoFTpoIYFHuzEwibidEXb0q8ECdACJhRO3Z23b3shMaIXdhlCxCZMXSABVGDcOgAYX047dxiQAHpz0hSABrEAcRdIcodDC0z1Lld7Qu0tGILe7-cj1pJ1TwvK9b3vR9KgmBEn1ZNVoDgBoADlyAPP05ggaRPTreMG1Nc0LCtXEPltAV7QsLZnUfV0kDYc5gw5UdsjDJAI2HaNYwQBMBSTFNVifLNH29X1-TY4sHDLctq1ZPUDTwk0mxbaAR0JTtu1HBcc0mQdh0I7hJ2nc4aHnd8RGXVcQHXYF-z3EIgJPM9L2vO8H2058IFfZA+xzCyvx-SkIFswDjxApzwNcqDslgm5yiAA)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for! I opted for the curried version to easier pass it as a filter to the `filter` function of Array.